# Oracle | Using SQL | To write a query to change the data timeframe from 5 minutes to customised minutes (30,60,120,240)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called cash_intra.

The data is pumped every five minutes to this table.
I want to write a query so that i can change the timeframe to
30 mins , 60 mins , 120 mins ,240 mins.

The data pumping starts at 09:15 and ends around 15:25 every 5 minutes.
I want a query that can convert this 5 minutes data to 30 minutes(and 60,120,240).

Also, Find , First Value , Last Value , Minimum and Maximum value after converting the timeframe.

The problem is that for 30 minutes time frame is coming
from 09:15 to 09:50, instead of 09:15 to 09:45 (30 minutes)

I have tried writing the below query. input is in minutes.

This table has the below DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE CASH_INTRA
(
SYMBOL  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
UDATE   DATE,
OPEN    FLOAT(126),
HIGH    FLOAT(126),
LOW     FLOAT(126),
CLOSE   FLOAT(126),
VOLUME  INTEGER,
)
```

select distinct symbol,udate_new,open_new,high_new,low_new,close_new,vol_new from
(

```
        select a.*
        ,min(udate) over (partition by symbol,trunc(udate),sr order by sr desc ) UDATE_NEW
        ,first_value(open) over (partition by symbol,trunc(udate),sr ORDER BY symbol,trunc(udate) desc,sr,MIN  ) OPEN_new
        ,max(high) over (partition by symbol,trunc(udate),sr ORDER BY symbol,trunc(udate) desc,sr  ) HIGH_new
        ,min(low) over (partition by symbol,trunc(udate),sr ORDER BY symbol,trunc(udate) desc,sr  ) LOW_new
        ,first_value(close) over (partition by symbol,trunc(udate),sr ORDER BY symbol,trunc(udate) desc,sr,min desc  ) CLOSE_new
        ,sum(volume) over (partition by symbol,trunc(udate),sr ORDER BY symbol,trunc(udate) desc,sr  ) vol_new

        from 
        (
            Select    a.*
            , 24*60 * (a.udate-15/(24*60) -to_date(to_char(a.udate,'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' 09:00:00' ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))             MIN
            ,floor(((a.udate-15/(24*60) -to_date(to_char(a.udate,'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' 09:00:00' ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24*60)/minutes) SR
            from cash_intra a  
            where 
            1=1
            and a.udate > to_date('01-02-2021','DD-MM-YYYY')
            order by symbol,a.udate desc

        ) a order by symbol,udate desc
    ) order by symbol,udate_new desc
```

- Actual Data : [In 5 Minutes]

| SYMBOL | UDATE | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:25:00 | 16.4 | 16.45 | 16.4 | 16.4 | 787015 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:20:00 | 16.4 | 16.45 | 16.35 | 16.45 | 3503044 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:15:00 | 16.35 | 16.45 | 16.35 | 16.4 | 5082249 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:10:00 | 16.25 | 16.4 | 16.2 | 16.35 | 9113142 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:05:00 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 16.25 | 16.25 | 2348478 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:00:00 | 16.2 | 16.3 | 16.2 | 16.25 | 2167321 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:55:00 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 16.2 | 16.25 | 1782746 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:50:00 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 16.2 | 16.25 | 1473975 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:45:00 | 16.3 | 16.3 | 16.2 | 16.25 | 1650834 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:40:00 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 758533 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:35:00 | 16.2 | 16.3 | 16.15 | 16.3 | 3542270 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:30:00 | 16.2 | 16.2 | 16.15 | 16.2 | 1206264 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:25:00 | 16.2 | 16.2 | 16.15 | 16.15 | 1332780 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:20:00 | 16.15 | 16.2 | 16.15 | 16.2 | 650918 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:15:00 | 16.15 | 16.2 | 16.05 | 16.2 | 6078391 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:10:00 | 16.1 | 16.15 | 16.1 | 16.15 | 833415 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:05:00 | 16.2 | 16.2 | 16.1 | 16.1 | 1587571 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:00:00 | 16.2 | 16.2 | 16.15 | 16.15 | 956828 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:55:00 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 16.15 | 16.2 | 3328170 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:50:00 | 16.35 | 16.35 | 16.25 | 16.3 | 1872855 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:45:00 | 16.3 | 16.35 | 16.25 | 16.35 | 2026572 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:40:00 | 16.3 | 16.4 | 16.25 | 16.25 | 6296412 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:35:00 | 16.2 | 16.3 | 16.15 | 16.3 | 4222645 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:30:00 | 16.1 | 16.25 | 16.05 | 16.2 | 5678808 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:25:00 | 16.1 | 16.1 | 16.05 | 16.05 | 1173837 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:20:00 | 16.1 | 16.1 | 16.05 | 16.1 | 1138152 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:15:00 | 16.05 | 16.1 | 16 | 16.1 | 1134656 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:10:00 | 16.1 | 16.1 | 16 | 16.05 | 2240108 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:05:00 | 16.05 | 16.1 | 16 | 16.1 | 3673388 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:00:00 | 16.1 | 16.1 | 16 | 16.05 | 2368639 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:55:00 | 16.05 | 16.1 | 16 | 16.05 | 2745855 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:50:00 | 15.9 | 16.05 | 15.85 | 16 | 4361684 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:45:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.85 | 15.85 | 1397722 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:40:00 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 593454 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:35:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 346498 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:30:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 416777 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:25:00 | 15.85 | 15.95 | 15.8 | 15.95 | 1550090 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:20:00 | 15.9 | 15.9 | 15.8 | 15.8 | 734989 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:15:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.85 | 15.85 | 2599963 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:10:00 | 15.95 | 16 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 1654169 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:05:00 | 15.95 | 16 | 15.9 | 16 | 1422148 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:00:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 991175 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:55:00 | 15.95 | 16 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 1775197 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:50:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 1243049 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:45:00 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 15.85 | 15.95 | 2362112 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:40:00 | 15.9 | 15.9 | 15.85 | 15.9 | 717400 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:35:00 | 15.9 | 15.9 | 15.85 | 15.9 | 573491 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:30:00 | 15.9 | 15.95 | 15.8 | 15.9 | 2175128 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:25:00 | 15.85 | 15.9 | 15.8 | 15.9 | 3243313 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:20:00 | 15.85 | 15.9 | 15.8 | 15.85 | 1699236 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:15:00 | 15.75 | 15.85 | 15.7 | 15.85 | 1151059 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:10:00 | 15.75 | 15.75 | 15.7 | 15.75 | 578458 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:05:00 | 15.7 | 15.75 | 15.65 | 15.75 | 2931645 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:00:00 | 15.85 | 15.85 | 15.7 | 15.7 | 1483777 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:55:00 | 15.85 | 15.85 | 15.8 | 15.8 | 930843 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:50:00 | 15.8 | 15.85 | 15.75 | 15.85 | 1523350 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:45:00 | 15.75 | 15.8 | 15.75 | 15.8 | 657759 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:40:00 | 15.8 | 15.8 | 15.75 | 15.8 | 726103 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:35:00 | 15.75 | 15.8 | 15.7 | 15.8 | 1654956 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:30:00 | 15.7 | 15.75 | 15.65 | 15.7 | 913641 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:25:00 | 15.65 | 15.75 | 15.6 | 15.7 | 3119643 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:20:00 | 15.6 | 15.65 | 15.55 | 15.65 | 854041 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:15:00 | 15.6 | 15.6 | 15.55 | 15.6 | 673388 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:10:00 | 15.55 | 15.6 | 15.55 | 15.6 | 806053 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:05:00 | 15.6 | 15.6 | 15.45 | 15.6 | 3962093 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:00:00 | 15.6 | 15.6 | 15.5 | 15.55 | 2470349 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:55:00 | 15.6 | 15.6 | 15.5 | 15.6 | 3466551 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:50:00 | 15.65 | 15.65 | 15.55 | 15.6 | 3053935 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:45:00 | 15.55 | 15.65 | 15.55 | 15.6 | 1977711 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:40:00 | 15.55 | 15.6 | 15.5 | 15.6 | 1728704 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:35:00 | 15.6 | 15.65 | 15.55 | 15.55 | 3252134 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:30:00 | 15.65 | 15.7 | 15.5 | 15.6 | 5555440 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:25:00 | 15.8 | 15.8 | 15.65 | 15.65 | 3370366 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:20:00 | 15.9 | 15.9 | 15.8 | 15.85 | 4136299 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.05 | 15.85 | 15.9 | 6181939 |

**- Expected Data [in 30 Mins]**

| SYMBOL | UDATE | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:15:00 | 16.35 | 16.45 | 16.35 | 16.4 | 9372308 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:45:00 | 16.3 | 16.4 | 16.2 | 16.35 | 18536496 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:15:00 | 16.15 | 16.3 | 16.05 | 16.3 | 13569156 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:45:00 | 16.3 | 16.35 | 16.1 | 16.15 | 10605411 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:15:00 | 16.05 | 16.4 | 16 | 16.25 | 19644510 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:45:00 | 15.95 | 16.1 | 15.85 | 16.05 | 16787396 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:15:00 | 15.95 | 15.95 | 15.8 | 15.95 | 6241771 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:45:00 | 15.9 | 16 | 15.85 | 15.95 | 9447850 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:15:00 | 15.75 | 15.95 | 15.7 | 15.9 | 9559627 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:45:00 | 15.75 | 15.85 | 15.65 | 15.75 | 8105832 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:15:00 | 15.6 | 15.8 | 15.55 | 15.8 | 7941772 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:45:00 | 15.55 | 15.65 | 15.45 | 15.6 | 15736692 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.05 | 15.5 | 15.6 | 24224882 |

**- Expected Data [in 60 Mins]**

| SYMBOL | UDATE | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 15:15:00 | 16.35 | 16.45 | 16.35 | 16.4 | 9372308 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 14:15:00 | 16.15 | 16.4 | 16.05 | 16.35 | 32105652 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:15:00 | 16.05 | 16.4 | 16 | 16.15 | 30249921 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 12:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.1 | 15.8 | 16.05 | 23029167 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:15:00 | 15.75 | 16 | 15.7 | 15.95 | 19007477 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 10:15:00 | 15.6 | 15.85 | 15.55 | 15.75 | 16047604 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.05 | 15.45 | 15.6 | 39961574 |

- **Expected Data [in 120 Mins]**

| SYMBOL | UDATE | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.4 | 15.8 | 16.15 | 53279088 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 11:15:00 | 15.6 | 16 | 15.55 | 15.95 | 35055081 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.05 | 15.45 | 15.6 | 39961574 |

- **Expected Data [in 240 Mins]**

| SYMBOL | UDATE | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 13:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.45 | 15.8 | 16.4 | 94757048 |
| YESK | 01/02/2021 09:15:00 | 15.95 | 16.05 | 15.45 | 15.95 | 75016655 |

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would a simplified db<>fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Edited Question to add sample data and expected data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : can you help